# Polynom( ) in Polynom cannot be applied to (float[], double)

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Только начала изучать Java, возникает ошибка "Polynom( )  in Polynom cannot be applied to (float[], double)" во втором коде. Можете объснить, что она значит и как её исправить?
Два кода располагаются в разных файлах.

```
    public class Polynom {

        private float[] coef;
        private double point;
        private double value = 0;

        public double valueAtPoint(float[] coef, float point){
            for(int i = coef.length; i > 0; i--){
                value = (value + coef[i]) * point;
            }
            value = value + coef[0];
            return value;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return "Value at point " + point + ": " + value;
        }
    }

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Polynom p = new Polynom(new float[] {2, 4, 3}, 10.6);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Метод не применяется ни к double, ни к float, ни к int.

Comment: Ещё один совет. 10.6 - это double, 10.6F - это float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете объект класса Polinom используя конструктор Polinom(float[] x, double d)

```
Polynom p = new Polynom(new float[] {2, 4, 3}, 10.6);
```

Но, судя по вашему коду, у вас такого конструктора нет, поэтому вызывается конструктор по умолчанию Polinom(), в который вы пытаетесь передать данные. Определите новый конструктор в вашем классе Polinom.

```
public Polinom(float[] coef, double point) {
    this.coef = coef;
    this.point = point;
}
```

Comment: Все так, а Я сослепу перепутал метод и конструктор